# Puffball growing on a tree: What kind of mushroom is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

What kind of mushroom/fungus is the one shown in the photos?

**Description:** Looks similar in size (~4-5 cm as I  remember) and shape to a puffball. It is not hard to the touch, unlike typical mushrooms that grow on trees. Several balls were growing individually (not in clusters) from the 2-3 m tall stump of a broken tree, at multiple locations from the bottom to the top. They were breaking through the bark from the inside.

**Time and location:** Saxony, Germany, in a mixed forest. Early September.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! Do you happen to know the species of tree this stump is from? Knowing the "host" can be important for identifying fungi. The leaves in the background look like they could be from European beech, but the bark doesn't look right to me ...

Comment: @tyersome Yes, the background is beech. This tree I don't know, and I can't tell from the photo. If I get the chance to go back this week, I'll take a closer look and will try to figure it out. Maybe by then the mushroom fruiting bodies will have developed enough to give us some more hints.

Comment: Most trees are beech in this forest, but there's also plenty of oak, birch, conifers, and other things.

Comment: they look like mosaic puffball mushrooms (Lycoperdon utriforme), which do grow in Germany, but they don't grow on trees :-/ I don't know what these are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe these are [*Fomitopsis betulina*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/piptoporus_betulinus.html) (= *Piptoporus betulinus*), the Birch Conk (or Birch Polypore or Tinder Polypore), a common mushroom [throughout the Northern hemisphere](https://www.first-nature.com/fungi/piptoporus-betulinus.php).

[image: sample image]
<sup>Fig. 1. Young *Fomitopsis betulina* emerging from a downed birch log. image: [Eric](https://mushroomobserver.org/users/22762) ([CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/))</sup>

The diagnostic features here are the scattered fruiting on dead wood, the off-white, crackling surface, and the shape. *F. betulina* is not a puffball, but a polypore like other shelf fungi that grow off the sides of dead trees. Unlike other shelf fungi, they remain fairly soft. These young specimens resemble puffballs, but will expand to expose the pores on their underside. Read about *F. betulina* and see images of mature mushrooms [here](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/piptoporus_betulinus.html) and [here](https://mushroomobserver.org/observations?q=1nZnL).

*F. betulina* grows exclusively on birch, and the snag it is growing on appears to be birch based on the light color and horizontal lenticels. Birches do have similar leaves to beeches, though the surrounding trees could be different species.

Comment: Thanks for the guess! Looking at photos of _F. betulina_, the top and the bottom looks different (the top is brownish and round, the bottom is flat). This one was more or less symmetric. I don't recall seeing any which looked asymmetric, but then it was two years ago ... Yes, this is a lone birch stump and the surrounding trees are beeches.

Comment: @Szabolcs The mature mushrooms I linked earlier don't really look like what you found, but see the image I just added - when they're young, they don't have the pore surface on the bottom.

Comment: Looks convincing enough!